How to solve this create_person.py
I am trying to run this using VSCode.
The first script add_student.py works fine.
However the second script, create_person.py gives me the following error:
> > `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Face Recognition and RFID\create_person.py", line 13, in <module>
res = CF.person.create(personGroupId, str(sys.argv[1]))
> >           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\vkurt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cognitive_face\person.py", line 71, in create
return util.request('POST', url, json=json)
> >            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\vkurt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cognitive_face\util.py", line 103, in request
raise CognitiveFaceException(response.status_code,
cognitive_face.util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:
status_code: 401
code: 401
message: Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.`

I am trying to record face_recognition, I tried other replies about this problem on other posters but can't figure how to solve. This is the code:
import sys
import cognitive_face as CF
from global_variables import personGroupId, Key, endpoint
import sqlite3

personGroupId = 'user'
CF.BaseUrl.set(endpoint)
CF.Key.set(Key)
if len(sys.argv) != 1:
    res = CF.person.create(personGroupId, str(sys.argv[1]))
    print(res)
    extractId = str(sys.argv[1])[-2:]
    connect = sqlite3.connect("Face-DataBase")
    cmd = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = " + extractId
    cursor = connect.execute(cmd)
    isRecordExist = 0
    for row in cursor:                                                          
        isRecordExist = 1
    if isRecordExist == 1:                                                      
        connect.execute("UPDATE Students SET personID = ? WHERE ID = ?",(res['personId'], extractId))
    connect.commit()                                                           
    connect.close()
    print("Person ID successfully added to the database")


Did you check if your variables "endpoint" and "Key" are valid? Last line of error message is rather clear, where to look...

The error message itself tells you what is wrong. It says: "Access denied due to invalid subscription key [...]. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription". In your code you provide the key by doing CF.Key.set(Key). Are you sure that this Key variable is correct? I see it is defined in a separate file, global_variables. Is the API key for Face up to date and working?

Where can I get valid endpoint and Key variables? Can you provide me ways to do it, or any link that I can use? Thanks.
